# How to install/remove/upgrade .rpm packages on Red Hat?

Tags: command-line, rhel, software-installation, rpm

I need to install a package that is missing in my virtual machine that is running Red Hat. How do I do that?

What command should I use to install/remove/upgrade .rpm packages?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**EDIT:** As recommended in a comment below, you can just use `yum` for everything and you will be fine.

Check [Red Hat's documentation](https://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-rpm-using.html) for the `rpm` command.

Basically:

- `rpm -Uvh package_file.rpm` installs/upgrades a package **from a .rpm file**
- `rpm -e package_name` removes a package

To install packages from Red Hat's repositories, use [`yum`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/yum), whose commands are mostly self-explanatory (`install`, `update` etc...). [This documentation](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/yum/) is for CentOS 5, but I think it should work for newer versions of Red Hat/CentOS.

Comment: As [this page of the RHEL6 Deployment Guide](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-RPM.html) explains, you should only use `rpm` if absolutely necessary -- under normal circumstances, there's no reason to use the above-mentioned `rpm` commands to play with the package database; `yum install package_file.rpm` and `yum remove package_name` will do just fine.

Comment: @ryran sweet, I didn't know that (haven't used rpm-based distros in quite a while). Edited my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

RTFM: `man yum`. `apropos install` leads to the rights track.

If "apropos" does not return anything, you have to run `makewhatis` first.

After that you will find almost anything with "apropos" which will do a full-text-search of all man-page-short-descriptions.

yum, as opposed to rpm, will resolve all dependencies needed.

Comment: For the record, `apropos` only searches the names and short descriptions of man pages, in contrast to what you describe. `man -K` on the other hand...

Comment: @ryran thanks - I corrected it. On CentOS 5 `man -k` does the same as `apropos`, according to the man-page and to a test.

Answer (score 2):

Install rpm:

```
rpm -ivh abcd.rpm
```

Update rpm:

```
rpm -Uvh abcdef.rpm
```

Remove rpm:

```
rpm -e abcd.rpm
```

or remove the rpm without dependencies:

```
rpm -e --nodeps abcd.rpm
```